# How to use scala.util.Sorting.quickSort() with arbitrary types?

Tags: scala

I need to sort an array of pairs by second element. How do I pass comparator for my pairs to the quickSort function?
I'm using the following ugly approach now:

```
type AccResult = (AccUnit, Long) // pair
class Comparator(a:AccResult) extends Ordered[AccResult] {
        def compare(that:AccResult) = lessCompare(a, that)
        def lessCompare(a:AccResult, that:AccResult) = if (a._2 == that._2) 0 else if (a._2 < that._2) -1 else 1
}
scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(data)(d => new Comparator(d))
```

Why is quickSort designed to have an ordered view instead of usual comparator argument?

Scala 2.7 solutions are preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure exactly what you are unhappy about what you are currently doing, but perhaps all you are looking for is this?

```
implicit def toComparator(a: AccResult) = new Comparator(a)
scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(data)
```

If, on the other hand, the problem is that the tuple *is* `Ordered` and you want a *different* ordering, well, that's why it changed on Scala 2.8.

*** EDIT ***

Ouch! Sorry, I only now realize you said you preferred Scala 2.7 solutions. I have editted this answer soon to put the solution for 2.7 above. What follows is a 2.8 solution.

Scala 2.8 expects an `Ordering`, not an `Ordered`, which is a context bound, not a view bound. You'd write your code in 2.8 like this:

```
type AccResult = (AccUnit, Long) // pair 
implicit object AccResultOrdering extends Ordering[AccResult] { 
        def compare(x: AccResult, y: AccResult) = if (x._2 == y._2) 0 else if (x._2 < y._2) -1 else 1 
}
```

Or maybe just:

```
type AccResult = (AccUnit, Long) // pair 
implicit val AccResultOrdering = Ordering by ((_: AccResult)._2)
```

And use it like:

```
scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(data)
```

On the other hand, the usual way to do sort in Scala 2.8 is just to call one of the sorting methods on it, such as:

```
data.sortBy((_: AccResult)._2)
```

Comment: The implicit object is broken b/c the parameters are x and y and the code handles a and that.

Comment: So, I still need to implement a custom class and use a view in 2.7. 2.8 is so much better. I can't wait its being adopted by debian testing.

Comment: @Basilevs I _do_ hope it gets adopted by testing. There's a real departure from 2.7 to 2.8. And, alas, 2.9 should be out early next year.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to prefer the non-implicit arguments unless its being used in more than a few places.

```
type Pair = (String,Int)
val items : Array[Pair] = Array(("one",1),("three",3),("two",2))
quickSort(items)(new Ordering[Pair] {
  def compare(x: Pair, y: Pair) = {
    x._2 compare y._2
  }
})
```

Edit: After learning about view bounds in another question, I think that this approach might be better:

```
val items : Array[(String,Int)] = Array(("one",1),("three",3),("two",2))

class OrderTupleBySecond[X,Y <% Comparable[Y]] extends Ordering[(X,Y)] {
  def compare(x: (X,Y), y: (X,Y)) = {
    x._2 compareTo y._2
  }
}

util.Sorting.quickSort(items)(new OrderTupleBySecond[String,Int])
```

In this way, OrderTupleBySecond could be used for any Tuple2 type where the type of the 2nd member of the tuple has a view in scope which would convert it to a Comparable.

Answer (score 2):

Have your type extend `Ordered`, like so:

```
case class Thing(number : Integer, name: String) extends Ordered[Thing] {
  def compare(that: Thing) = name.compare(that.name)
}
```

And then pass it to sort, like so:

```
val array = Array(Thing(4, "Doll"), Thing(2, "Monkey"), Thing(7, "Green"))
scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(array)
```

Printing the array will give you:

```
array.foreach{ e => print(e) }
>> Thing(4,Doll) Thing(7,Green) Thing(2,Monkey)
```

Comment: The type is fixed - it's a pair of (smth, Long). Second field is to be compared. How do I made this pair inherit from Ordered?

Comment: I think you should have a look at Colin's answer, I think it's the best one in this thread.